# Unable to get time difference between two dates

Tags: php, date, datetime

I am trying to find the time difference between an expiry date and today's date, but my code doesn't work.

```
$time_one=DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', get_field('expirydate'));
$time_two=new DateTime();

$timeleft = $time_one->diff($time_two);
echo $timeleft;
```

Comment: You get a [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) back from `DateTime::diff()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
echo $timeleft->format('%a days');
```

So when you apply [diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) function to DateTime object -> you receive a [DateInterval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) object. To access its properties about total difference between dates you should apply method called format.

Comment: When you apply diff function to DateTime object -> you receive a DateInterval object http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php. To access its propertie about total difference between dates you should apply method called format. http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php

Answer (score 0):

The `diff` method returns you an `DateInterval` object. You must format the output in order to see how many days, hours, minutes, seconds remained:

```
$dateTimeInTheFuture = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', get_field('expirydate'));

$dateInterval = $dateTimeInTheFuture->diff(new DateTime());

echo 'Time remained until expire: ' . $dateInterval->format('%d days, %h hours, %i minutes, %s seconds');
```

Read more about [DateInterval.format](http://php.net/manual/ro/dateinterval.format.php) method

Comment: how do i get it to display in hrs minute and seconds...i.e convert the days to hrs minutes seconds